# ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector is showing when app is running in Release configuration

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights

I am using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector 1.0.10 for my WPF .NET 4.6.2 application. The workflow is working fine, but the issue I encounter is the MinidumpUploader.exe console is showing when my app (in Release mode) is running.

I would like to know how to hide the MinidumpUploader.exe console, at least when my app is running in Release configuration.

Comment: Would you mind sharing demo code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @TomSun Actually it’s a known issue being tracked here : https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/638